# Visual Studio flat file connection manager

Tags: visual-studio

I'm following a Microsoft tutorial for SSIS and I'm currently on the following step in this link, [SSIS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-2-3-modifying-the-flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver16).

It's having me go into the flat file source data and edit the 'Expressions' property.  Once I follow the steps, VS crashes.  I've tried restarting VS and following the steps multiple times and VS still crashes after selecting "OK" on the dialog box.

[image]

Is there something in the settings I'm missing?